# The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "zsh" does not exist

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, zsh, manjaro

I try to use zsh as a shell in the integrated terminal in visual studio code but it does not work.

This is my `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "/bin/zsh"
        }
    }
}
```

When I open a new terminal I get `/bin/sh` as the shell. Using "bash" or "sh" instead of "zsh" works fine. Interestingly, when I `ls /bin` in the *integrated* terminal, `zsh` is not shown in the output. When I perform the same command in the normal terminal it does.
Additionally I can switch shell manually via `exec /bin/bash` / `exec /bin/zsh` in the normal terminal but in the *integrated* terminal it complains that "No such file or directory" exists for zsh.

If I use `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "zsh"` in  the `settings.json` I get the error "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "zsh" does not exist.".

PS: I am using Manjaro linux with zsh as the pre-installed default shell.

Output of `w`, *integrated* terminal:

```
18:21:41 up  1:51,  0 users,  load average: 12,60, 11,30, 12,25
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

but `whoami` outputs `y`.

Output of `w`, normal terminal:

```
18:23:22 up  1:53,  3 users,  load average: 13,64, 12,04, 12,42
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
y        tty1      16:30    1:53m  2:29   0.08s /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
y        pts/0     16:30    1:53m  0.00s  4.37s /usr/bin/kded5
y        pts/3     18:23    2.00s  0.26s  0.00s w
```

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: @user It is corrected now, but yes. `/usr/bin/` and `/bin` link to the same directory, the later is  the link I recon. I tried both but with the same results.